# Counting paths from top left to bottom right of a matrix, moving only right or down

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming

The question is "The task is to count all the possible paths from top left to bottom right of a m X n matrix with the constraints that from each cell you can either move only to right or down."
My solution is

```
unordered_map<string,int> res;
int matrix(int m,int n){
    if(m==1&&n==1){
        return 1;
    }
    if(m==0||n==0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(res.find(to_string(m)+","+to_string(n))!=res.end()){
        // cout<<to_string(m)+","+to_string(n)<<endl;
       return res[to_string(m)+","+to_string(n)];
    }
    if (res.find(to_string(n)+","+to_string(m))!=res.end())
    {
        // cout<<to_string(n)+","+to_string(m)<<endl;
       return res[to_string(n)+","+to_string(m)];
    }
    res[to_string(m)+","+to_string(n)]= matrix(m-1,n)+matrix(m,n-1);
    return  res[to_string(m)+","+to_string(n)];
}
```

It fails for some test cases.The failed test case is 19 71.

Comment: please *explain* what you're doing.

Comment: Unless the online judge or competition site provide the input to your failed cases, there's no reliable way to replicate the problem and debug your program. Which is only *one* of the flaws with such sites.

Comment: those `to_string` should be replaced with `std::pair` or alike.

Comment: @appleapple The problem is that there's no standard hash-method for `std::pair`.

Comment: I have edited it please check. The failed case is 19 71.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude fair point. one also need to defined their own `Hash` if use `std::pair`

Comment: What do you expect `if (res.find(to_string(n)+","+to_string(m))!=res.end())` to do for you?

Comment: It is caching the values already known. If the value for m,n or n,m already exists then we do not calculate it alse we calculate and store it in hash map.if (res.find(to_string(n)+","+to_string(m))!=res.end()) checks it's existence.

Comment: Your program must be taking more input, to populate the map. Please try to create a [mre], and tell us the full input as well as the expected and actual output. And please use a debugger.

Comment: Please make the title describe the problem. "I can't figure out why my program doesn't work" applies to pretty much everything on this site. Is the problem that the lookup is not working? Is the problem in the algorithm itself? (Isn't the answer just C(m+n,n)?)

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)